# How to get python to read messages that a bot sent on discord

Tags: python, discord

There's a bot on Discord that let's you "grow" your own little pixel art plants but you have to water them at least once every two days so that they don't die. I've made a little code that waters my plants every 15 minutes by sending a message to the Discord channel where the bot is. At the moment, I have to insert my plant's names in a document I've created so that python can read it, however, I'd like it if it could get the plants names on it's own. If you send the bot a message saying "p.plants" to the channel where the bot is, it sends you a message with a list of your plants back. How can I get python to read that message and put all the plants on a list?
P.S.: I'm an absolute beginner, this is my first "real" project.
Here is my code so far:

```
import itertools
import sys
import threading
import time
import requests
import toml
from tqdm import tqdm


counter = "plants"
line_count = 0
with open(counter, "r") as files:
    for _ in files:
        line_count += 1

with open("config.toml") as f:
    config = toml.load(f)

token = config["token"]
channel = config["ChannelID"]


def countdown(start):
    return list(reversed(range(start + 1)))


def main():
    while True:
        start = input("Would you like to wake up the farmer?(Y/N) ").upper()
        if start == "Y":
            payload = {
                'content': "p.plants"
            }
            header = {
                'authorization': token
            }
            _ = requests.post(channel, data=payload, headers=header)
            loop_counter_message = input(
                "Would you like the farmer to send messages to your channel telling you how many "
                "times he has watered your plants? (Y/N)").upper()
            done = False

            def animate():
                for c in itertools.cycle(['.', '..', '...', '....', '.....']):
                    if done:
                        break
                    sys.stdout.write('\rWaking up the farmer ' + c)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(1)
                sys.stdout.write('\rDone! The farmer is awake and will now start watering your plants!     ')
                time.sleep(0.5)

            t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
            t.start()
            time.sleep(5)
            done = True
            loop_counter = 0
            while loop_counter >= 0:
                payload_counter = 0
                while payload_counter < line_count:
                    plants = open("plants", "r")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print("")
                    for plant in plants.readlines():
                        payload = {
                            'content': "p.water " + plant
                        }
                        print("Watering " + plant + "...")
                        header = {
                            'authorization': token
                        }
                        _ = requests.post(channel, data=payload, headers=header)
                        payload_counter += 1
                        time.sleep(1)
                        if payload_counter == line_count:
                            payload = {
                                'content': "p.exp"
                            }
                            header = {
                                'authorization': token
                            }
                            _ = requests.post(channel, data=payload, headers=header)
                            loop_counter += 1
                            print("")
                            print("All your plants have been watered!")
                            print("")
                            print("If at any time you wish to stop the farmer, press [E] for 1 second")
                            if loop_counter != 1:
                                print("So far, the farmer has watered your plants " + str(loop_counter) + " times.")
                                if loop_counter_message == "Y":
                                    payload = {
                                        'content': "So far, the farmer has watered your plants " + str(loop_counter)
                                                   + " times. "
                                    }
                                    header = {
                                        'authorization': token
                                    }
                                    _ = requests.post(channel, data=payload, headers=header)
                            else:
                                print("So far, the farmer has watered your plants " + str(loop_counter) + " time.")
                                if loop_counter_message == "Y":
                                    payload = {
                                        'content': "So far, the farmer has watered your plants " + str(
                                            loop_counter) + " time."
                                    }
                                    header = {
                                        'authorization': token
                                    }
                                    _ = requests.post(channel, data=payload, headers=header)
                            for _ in tqdm(countdown(2619)):
                                plants.close()
                                time.sleep(0.3333333)

        elif start == "N":
            print("Ok, the farmer will stay asleep for now")
            time.sleep(2)
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid command")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: does the bot return the plants in like `plant1, plant2, plant3` ? Also, does this bot reads command inputs from other bots? Because usually bots don't read message commands made by other bots

Comment: Unfortunately no… the bot sends a message saying the name of the plant, what type of plant it is and how long it has been alive for, it does this for every plant. I don’t think the bot responds to other bots, however, with that code it is as if I’m sending the messages, not another bot